# How do I manually install extensions on Chrome for OS X?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, installation

Where is the extension folder for Chrome on OS X? Since I haven't installed any extensions yet, how can I configure it to work properly with Chrome on OS X?

I don't want to browse the extensions gallery but rather install my own extensions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, when you look at your currently installed extensions (even if there aren't any), click on the "Developer Mode" link. This should show you a button labeled "Load unpacked extension..." -- that's the main way to load your own extensions.

You can also review your published extensions on the developer dashboard. On the page for browsing extensions, look for the link that says "Publish your extensions" on the left side. That should take you to a [developer dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/developer/dashboard?hl=en-US), you'll probably be prompted to log in to your google account first.

Google provides [tons of help](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/index.html) building Chrome extensions. Try the [Getting Started](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html) page.

*The direct answer to your question is that Chrome extensions are stored in: /Users/**username**/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions but you probably shouldn't try to manipulate things directly there -- use the tools within the browser.*

Comment: addition: if you try to modify the extension folder, it wont work - chrome will erase everything that isnt defined and signed within the chrome executable while chrome is running.

Answer (score 6):

In OS X Lion the Chrome extension folder is here:

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default
```

If you cannot see `Library` folder, you may open Finder, choose `Go > Go to Folder...`, then type `~/Library` and hit Enter. After that, you can browse Chrome folder.

Comment: Quite annoying that the Library folder in the user folder is hidden ~:|

Comment: To view Library folder choose Go, then press ALT and the library folder will show.